# Bash builtin read command difference from Korn shell

Tags: bash

I use the following script to retrieve information about mounted file-systems on several hundred Solaris (v9,10,11) and Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v5,6,7) servers for analysis.

```
# retrieves for all mounted file-systems: server, device, allocated, used, available, percent_used, mount_directory, permissions, owner_name, and group_name

server=$(uname -n)
df -h | awk '
    NF == 6 { print ($0); } 
    NF == 1 { device = $1; } 
    NF == 5 { print (device, " ", $0); }
  ' | while read device allocated used available percent mount
do
  ls -ld "${mount}" | read permissions links owner_name group_name size month day time directory
  echo "${server} ${device} ${allocated} ${used} ${available} ${percent} ${mount} ${permissions} ${owner_name} ${group_name}"
done
```

I perform this operation from Windoze using PuTTY "plink" utility.

```
plink -m filesys.script server_name >>filesys.txt
```

All worked as expected until my default shell was changed from ksh to bash on all servers.  Now, the second read command that obtains ls output for permissions, owner_name, and group_name is not functioning and does not produce any error messages either. Therefore the result is that only seven tokens are in output (server through mount) and there is nothing for permissions, owner_name, or group_name.

I have confirmed that if I upload the script to the Unix server with a shebang (#!/bin/ksh) at the top line the script works as expected.  However, I do not want to push this script to hundreds of servers and maintain the script in a distributed mechanism.  I would like to retain the script on central Windoze workstation and call with -m parameter of plink.  Placing a shabang at top of the file does not execute ksh using plink -m option.

The Bash shell versions that are in play are 3.2 and 4.1.  I have also made certain that the Windoze script file has carriage returns removed.  The awk utility is used to handle situations where the device name is too long and df breaks the output over two lines.

Again, the first read (from df/awk) is working fine but the second (ls output) is not.  I confirmed by placing a 'set' following the second read and those environment varriables were not in the environment.

Comment: Minor bit of pedantry: These are regular shell variables, not environment variables.

Comment: (Also, using `ls` programatically is bad form; http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs in general, and the "getting metadata on a file" section in particular).

Comment: For an actually fully pertinent answer to your question, see BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: You might also consider using `df -P`, which will cause `df` to emit in a format specified by POSIX; otherwise, its output format is locally specified and can vary between platforms. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/df.html

Comment: BTW, bash *is* able to behave the way you expect under a series of conditions (among them, only in cases with job control disabled) if the `lastpipe` option is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` (as a pipe element) happens in a subshell, so even though it actually *does* execute perfectly, once that pipeline exits its results aren't available to the `echo` running on a separate line (as part of the parent process that originally spawned the pipeline). This is fully allowed by POSIX; which component of a pipeline, if any, is performed by the shell spawning that pipeline is unspecified by the standard and thus implementation-defined.

You can address the issue by putting the `echo` inside of the same pipeline element as the `read`:

```
server=$(uname -n)
df -h | awk '
    NF == 6 { print ($0); } 
    NF == 1 { device = $1; } 
    NF == 5 { print (device, " ", $0); }
  ' | while read device allocated used available percent mount
do
  # NOTE: parsing output from "ls" is unreliable
  ls -ld "${mount}" | {
    read permissions links owner_name group_name size month day time directory
    echo "${server} ${device} ${allocated} ${used} ${available} ${percent} ${mount} ${permissions} ${owner_name} ${group_name}"
  }
done
```

References:

- [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) (I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?)
- [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1))

If you have GNU `stat` or `find`, either of which allows you to provide a format string to control metadata output, I would strongly suggest using them in place of `ls -l` for parsing metadata. Even `perl` is somewhat better for the purpose, having only a single universally available implementation with uniform `stat` behavior between releases.